# SSL forwarding for just one subdomain in .htaccess

Tags: ssl, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have Apache(ubuntu) server and I need to force `https` just for `sub1.domain.com`.
Currently all traffic are being forwarded

> ```
> RewriteEngine On                                     
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off                             
> RewriteRule (.*) xxxx://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
> ```

The thing is my server is accessible on multiple domain like:

```
www.domain1.com
www.domain2.com
```

I only need to force `https` on one subdomain of my primary domain
`sub1.domain.com`

I have no idea how to write commands in `.htaccess`

PS: i wrote xxxx as this won't allow me to write https :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding another condition for that specific host on the server variable **`%{HTTP_HOST}`** (`[NC]` means **n**o **c**ase and makes the test case-insensitive):

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.domain\.com [NC]
> RewriteRule (.*) xxxx://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
> ```